# Open form submit in new window without popup blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, popup

I try to open the result of an form submit in a new window/tab. The submit is executed, after the user selects an option in a dropdown.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/result.html" method="post" target="_blank">
      <select>
        <option val="1">Opt 1</option>
        <option val="2">Opt 2</option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none;">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used this implementation after some research. The new window / submit is executed not automatically. Instead, I execute the submit after an interaction (change in the select field). Also, no other event is in between (e.g. ajax call). In my understanding: The script opens the new window from an [trusted event](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events) and the popup blocker should not prevent this. But that's exactly what happens.

Even the simple implementation above triggers currently the popup block in Google Chrome (Mac, 63.0) and Firefox (57.0.3).

Is there now no way to open a form result in a new window, without being on a whitelist?